# Implementing multiplication operator for mathematical functions C++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have the following abstract base class:

```
class Function {
 virtual double Eval(double x) const = 0;
};
```

I want to be able to use expressions like f * g or f->operator *(g), where f and g are concrete objects of the class Function, in my main file, say for example when I want to calculate a definite integral so that I can write:

```
AnIntegrationMethod(f*g);
```

A rather unsophisticated method I came up with consists of declaring a class Product (only header file shown, the implementation is obvious):

```
class Product: public Function {
 public: Product(Function *g, Function *f); 
  ~Product(); 
  virtual double Eval(double x) const; //return _g->Eval(x)*_f->Eval(x)
 private: Function *_g; Function *_f;
 };
```

and then in any of my functions

```
#include "Product.h"

class ConcreteFunction: public Function {
 public: 
   ConcreteFunction(); 
  ~ConcreteFunction(); 
  virtual double Eval(double x) const;
 Function* operator*(Function *f) {return new Product(this, f);}
 };
```

This actually works for simple stuff but the problem is that the operator * is only defined within single derived classes of the base class instead of being defined for every possible derived class. This means, for instance, that if I have a concrete object f representing a mathematical function I can call f->operator *g but if I want to call again the operator * to get the object (f->operator * g)->operator * f I am not going to be able to because the function f* g does not have the * operator defined as f.

I suppose I should define the operator * directly in my base class but then I can't figure out how to implement the operator because I don't really know how to get the proper Eval function for the product since I cannot use the class Product now, it wouldn't make sense to use the class Product derived from the class Function in the class Function itself. I think I'm also quite confused over whether in general is correct to write something like the following:

```
 Function* Function::operator*(Function *f) {
 Function *g;
 ...
 //operations that allow g to be have the right Eval function
 //which should of the sort this->Eval(x) * f->Eval(x)
 ...
 return g;
 }
```

Any hints or suggestions on how to proceed are appreciated. My level is very basic, I've been programming two month now.

Comment: The 'return new ...' is a memory leak, likely. (Or a design nightmare)

Comment: Are you multiplying functions (math expressions) or the values evaluated from the functions?  Does multiplying functions (math expressions) make sense?

Comment: Nothing good will come from this design.  If I am understanding what you are wanting to do, you will most likely either want to play with vectors, or create your own template for generic classing.

Comment: I posted a basic template solution that will work on the stack and not force you to use dynamic allocation and auto-deletion.

Answer (score 4):

Just a sketch, you might do something like this:

```
#include <memory>

// Base Function: f(x) = x
class Function
{
    protected:
    struct Implementation
    {
        virtual ~Implementation() {}
        virtual double evaluate(double x) const { return x; }
    };

    public:
    Function()
    :   self(std::make_shared<Implementation>())
    {}

    double operator () (double x) const { return self->evaluate(x); }

    protected:
    Function(std::shared_ptr<Implementation> self)
    :   self(self)
    {}

    private:
    std::shared_ptr<Implementation> self;
};
typedef Function Identity;


// Unary Function: u(-f(x))
class UnaryMinus : public Function
{
    protected:
    struct Implementation : Function::Implementation
    {
        Function f;
        Implementation(Function f)
        :   f(f)
        {};

        virtual double evaluate(double x) const override { return -f(x); }
    };

    public:
    UnaryMinus(Function f)
    :   Function(std::make_shared<Implementation>(f))
    {}
};

// Binary Function: u(f(x) + g(x))
class BinaryAdd : public Function
{
    protected:
    struct Implementation : Function::Implementation
    {
        Function f;
        Function g;
        Implementation(Function f, Function g)
        :   f(f), g(g)
        {};

        virtual double evaluate(double x) const override { return f(x) + g(x); }
    };

    public:
    BinaryAdd(Function f, Function g)
    :   Function(std::make_shared<Implementation>(f, g))
    {}
};

// Binary Function: u(f(x) * g(x))
class BinaryMultiply : public Function
{
    protected:
    struct Implementation : Function::Implementation
    {
        Function f;
        Function g;
        Implementation(Function f, Function g)
        :   f(f), g(g)
        {};

        virtual double evaluate(double x) const override { return f(x) * g(x); }
    };

    public:
    BinaryMultiply(Function f, Function g)
    :   Function(std::make_shared<Implementation>(f, g))
    {}
};

inline UnaryMinus operator - (Function f) { return UnaryMinus(f); }
inline BinaryAdd operator + (Function f, Function g) { return BinaryAdd(f, g); }
inline BinaryMultiply operator * (Function f, Function g) { return BinaryMultiply(f, g); }

#include <iostream>
int main() {
    Identity x;
    Function result = -x * (x + x) + x;
    std::cout << result(2) << '\n';
}
```

Comment: It's crazy that it has to be that complicated, but the end result looks quite nice!  I thought Product operator*(const Function &f, const Function &g) { return Product(f, g); } would be enough but in chains of operations it can't take the address of an intermediate Product.  You solve that issue by passing the operands by copy and hiding the implementations and real inheritance inside the class.

Comment: Question: in your code why is it valid to set `result` equal to a subclass?  Why doesn't that result in some kind of typing error?

Comment: @jschultz410 The 'class Function' handles polymorphism internally.

Comment: I think I basically understand how your code works. I don't understand why it is legal C++ to say Function f = BinaryAdd(Identity(), Identity());  Why doesn't that assignment result in a type error?  Some kind of implicit type conversion?

Comment: @jschultz410 Simple: BinaryAdd is a (!) Function

Comment: Ugh, I'm pretty lost.  I thought polymorphism like that only worked with pointers and references.  I didn't think you could set base classes equal to derived classes in general.

Comment: @jschultz410 Basically you are right, but here ' Function' encapsulates the polymorphism

Comment: So, it's legal and works because there is an implicit copy constructor in Function that, if it were explicit, would look like: Function(const Function &cpy) : self(cpy.self) {} and since the subclasses don't contain any other data necessary to their proper function this works because the particular implementation of cpy.self has the polymorphism and extra data needed built into it?

Answer (score 2):

You could overload `operator*` as a free-standing function. Put it in `Product.h/cpp` even if it is not a member of `Product`, since it is tightly related to it.

In `Product.h`:

```
Function* operator*(Function *f, Function *g);
```

In `Product.cpp`:

```
Function* operator*(Function *f, Function *g) {
    return new Product(f, g);
}
```

Same with addition, subtraction, etc.

Alternatively, you can implement them as member functions, but put the definition in `Function.cpp` and include `Product.h`, etc. there.

**Note** that your design has a huge flaw. You create `new` Function objects on the heap and pass around **pointers**. You need to `delete` them somewhere in your code, I assume in your deconstructors. But then you also need to [take care about copying your objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722). Usually, it is a nightmare to care about proper deletion manually, and there are automatic ways to do it (called "memory management"). You could consider using smart pointers, for example. Have a look at [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr). While not being most efficient in every case, it is a good thing to use in general when you first want to learn the language and not too many details about memory management. To apply `shared_ptr` to your code, replace every `Function*` with `shared_ptr<Function>`, and replace `new Function(...)` with `make_shared<Function>(...)` (and the same with other types).

**Also note** that `*` for math functions is ambiguous: In some contexts / literature, `f*g` means *multiplying the result*, while in others it means *function convolution*.

Comment: So how do you solve this problem for real in C++?  He wants to return a different derived class (Product) from operator* but doing it with new() will leak memory and I don't think you can return a reference properly, so you can't return a base class (e.g. - Function&).  So he has to return a Product by copy right: Product operator*(const Function &f, const Function &g) { return Product(f, g); }? And he should use references rather than pointers most everywhere else, right?

Comment: @jschultz410 Simply use smart pointers, not *raw* pointers. I guess unique_ptr can be used here, but if you don't want to think about it and are ok with a little overhead, you can simply use shared_ptr and you should be fine... `shared_ptr<Function> operator*(shared_ptr<Function> f, shared_ptr<Function> g) { return make_shared<Product>(f, g); }`

Comment: @jschultz410 And note that `return new` itself does not leak memory. Not deleting the returned pointer after you're done using the object is a leak. But where do you put the `delete` statement if you return it? That's a question which would have to be thought of when designing the program, if you decide to go for manual memory management with raw pointers. But since we have smart pointers, this should not be a valid option anymore.

Comment: So there is no way to do this on the stack?  You have to resort to new() and some kind of auto-cleanup mechanism?  I'm thinking in particular for intermediate values like: (f * g * h * z).eval(5)?

Comment: Thanks, I did it implementing the operator as a member function of Function.h/cpp. I think that what bothered me conceptually was that I had to include a header file of a derived class in the implementation file of the base class. Next step, doing it for real with smart pointers, I'm studying them right now.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a C++11 generic programming solution that doesn't rely on inherited polymorphism (i.e. - virtual functions) and doesn't require dynamic allocation.

I'm not a C++ expert and this can likely be improved upon significantly, but it works and gets the idea across.  In particular, the code below only works for functions of double's.  You can probably make the operands and return types be a template type too, so that this can generically work on different types (e.g. - complex) too.  I don't know the proper way to scope the template operators so that you can use the shorthand operator notation and not have them accidentally invoked on (or make ambiguous) other types that have operator()(double x).  If anyone has any suggestions to improve upon this answer, then please chime in and I'll edit my answer.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Identity
{
  double operator() (double x) const { return x; }
};

struct Constant
{
  template<typename T1>
  Constant(const T1 &x) : _x(x) {}

  double operator()(double x) const { return _x; }

private:
  double _x;
};


template<typename T1>
struct Negate
{
  Negate(const T1 &f) : _f(f) {}

  double operator() (double x) const { return -_f(x); }

private:
  T1 _f;
};

template<typename T1>
struct Reciprocal
{
  Reciprocal(const T1 &f) : _f(f) {}

  double operator() (double x) const { return 1 / _f(x); }

private:
  T1 _f;
};

template<typename T1, typename T2>
struct Sum
{
  Sum(const T1 &f, const T2 &g) : _f(f), _g(g) {}

  double operator() (double x) const { return _f(x) + _g(x); }

private:
  T1 _f;
  T2 _g;
};

template<typename T1, typename T2>
struct Product
{
  Product(const T1 &f, const T2 &g) : _f(f), _g(g) {}

  double operator() (double x) const { return _f(x) * _g(x); }

private:
  T1 _f;
  T2 _g;
};

template<typename T1> 
Negate<T1> operator-(const T1 &f) 
{ return Negate<T1>(f); }

template<typename T1, typename T2> 
Sum<T1, T2> operator+(const T1 &f, const T2 &g) 
{ return Sum<T1, T2>(f, g); }

template<typename T1, typename T2> 
Sum<T1, Negate<T2> > operator-(const T1 &f, const T2 &g) 
{ return Sum<T1, Negate<T2> >(f, Negate<T2>(g)); }

template<typename T1, typename T2> 
Product<T1, T2> operator*(const T1 &f, const T2 &g) 
{ return Product<T1, T2>(f, g); }

template<typename T1, typename T2> 
Product<T1, Reciprocal<T2> > operator/(const T1 &f, const T2 &g) 
{ return Product<T1, Reciprocal<T2> >(f, Reciprocal<T2>(g)); }


int main()
{
  auto f = (Identity() * Constant(4.0) + Constant(5)) / Identity();  // f(x) = (x * 4 + 5) / x; f(2) = 6.5
  auto g = f * f;                                                    // g(x) = f(x) * f(x);     g(2) = 42.25

  cout << f(2) << " " << g(2) << " " << (g / f)(2) << endl;  // prints 6.5 42.25 6.5

  return 0;
}
```

**EDIT**: The main drawback of this approach is that the type of a "formula" must be fully known at compile time and embedded in the template generated classes.  That means that very complicated formulas will generate lots of different classes and code.  So, this approach could lead to nasty code bloat.  Also, you can't do something like:

```
for (i = 1; i < j; ++i)  // raise f to the jth power (other than 0)
  f *= f;
```

Since the type of f must be fully known at compile time and the multiplication is invoking new types iteratively.  The other approaches that use a class hierarchy, dynamic allocation (with auto-cleanup) and polymorphism can do this though and don't have the problem of code bloat.  Still, it was interesting to try.