# How to overload arithmetic operators (+, *, -, /) for functions in c++?

Tags: c++11, math, operator-overloading, overloading, functor

I would like to implement a numerical integral whose integrand is evaluated at quadrature points. Therefore something like: `integral(domain, f)`, where `domain` is indeed the domain where I want to integrate and `f` is the function to integrate. f is only a function of the `Point p` (quadrature points) inside the domain and can have vector values (scalar is a particular case).

Since the function f can be, in general, a combination of different functions, I wonder how to overload arithmetic operators for functions.

I already found this [Implementing multiplication operator for mathematical functions C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28681108/implementing-multiplication-operator-for-mathematical-functions-c)
but it does not cover my question, because the `Function` returns only x, while In my case I would like to have different Functions which can return a more complex function of x.

So, let `f_1,...f_N` be different functions which have the same return type, for example a `std::array<double,M>` with given length M, and which receive the same input  `Point p`, i.e for I=1,...,N:

```
std::array<double,M> f_i(Point p)
      { std::array<double,M> x; 
        \\ compute x somehow depending on i
        return x;}
```

Then I would like to create `f` as a combination of the previous `f_1,...f_N`, e.g. `f=f_1 *f_2+(f_3*f_4)*f_5...` (here the operations are meant to be component wise).

In this way I could evaluate f(p) inside `integral(domain, f)`, obtaining for each quadrature point exactly:

```
f_1(p) *f_2(p)+(f_3(p)*f_4(p))*f_5(p)...
```

**Edit:**
I know I have to use functors and not simple functions (which I used just to state the problem), but I am not able to figure out how for this purpose.
Any hint?

Thank you

Comment: You cannot overload operators without a user defined data type being involved. `f_1 + f_2` for example can't be simple `std::array<double, M> (*)(Point)`s. But you can make a `template <class Return_type, class Args...> struct Math_function;` wrapper holding a callable which can then be overloaded and you can get `Math_function{f_1} + f_2;` to compile.

Comment: Yes, I used the name function, but I should have use functor maybe.

Comment: I'm a bit at a loss what you are asking. "Any hint?" isn't a real question and you seem to already know how to do it.

Comment: I know I have to use functors, but I am not able to figure out how for this purpose...

Comment: Make a wrapper for the functors and overload operators for the wrapper.